# google sitemap for tx_news records with dd_googlesitemap_dmf (or alternative)

Tags: typo3, sitemap, typo3-6.2.x

I try to let typo3 generate a sitemap for all the news records. For that I tried the dd_googlesitemap_dmf extention. The dd_googlesitemap works (it creates a sitemap for all the typo3 pages - but not for extensions). I filled in the basic infos into the configuration and called the url `?eID=dd_googlesitemap&sitemap=dmf&selector=news`, but all I get is a blank page (500 Internal Server Error).
The error:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'tx_ddgooglesitemap_ttnews' not found in [..]/typo3conf/ext/dd_googlesitemap_dmf/class.tx_ddgooglesitemap_dmf.php on line 43
```

I edited theext_typoscript_setup.txt in the extention and also tried to add the typoscript directly to the page template. Here is the version of the typoscript I use (all I changed is `pidList` and `singlePid`):

```
plugin.dd_googlesitemap_dmf {
    # selector for your extension (same as GET selector=news)
    news {

        # uid is NECESSARY in the sqlSelect field
        sqlMainTable = tx_news_domain_model_news

        # if catList depends of column of sqlMainTable (Column name like city or country)
        sqlCatColumn = 

        # if catList depends on sqlMMTable (Only works if uid_foreign and uid_local is in use)
        sqlMMTable = tx_news_domain_model_news_category_mm

        # order of the XML output
        sqlOrder = tstamp DESC

        # last modified timestamp column (inside of sqlMainTable)
        sqlLastUpdated = tstamp

        # sql column of the title
        sqlTitle = title

        # sql column of keywords
        sqlKeywords = keywords

        # frequency
        frequency = 1

        # typolink additionalParam (must belong to the uid of the sqlMainTable)
        linkParams = tx_news_pi1[news]

        # csv Pid's of the stored elements. Rootline is not checked with this setting
        pidList = 66

        # detail page id where the link should point at
        singlePid = 103

        # filter by category which is inside of the main table -> sqlCatColumn
        catList =

        # csv filter by mm related table -> sqlMMTable
        catMMList =

        # disable the language check through GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid
        disableLanguageCheck = 0
    }

    # sitemap eID urls for the crawler
    crawler {
        1 = http://beispiel.de?eID=dd_googlesitemap

        # more than one sitemap
        # 2 =  http://beispiel.de?eID=dd_googlesitemap&more-configuration
    }
}
```

Anyone got experience with this extention or got a good alternative?

Here the links to the ext.:

- http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dd_googlesitemap
- http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dd_googlesitemap_dmf

You can't install _dmf on a typo3 6.2 from the repo, (Dependencies <= 6.1.99), but the version on github works:
https://github.com/dohomi/dd_googlesitemap_dmf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to downgrade dd_googlesitemap (using 1.2.0 now) to get dd_googlesitemap_dmf to work

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the TYPO3 extension news provides a hook itself to generate sitemaps for news records. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/SitemapWithDdGoogleSitemap/Index.html for details